# VueJS 3 Create product filter dependent on each other

Tags: vue.js, filter, vuejs3, filtering, categories

I am trying to create a product filters that are dependent on each other like in e-commerce websites. Let's say I have selected X on the first option then the second filter should display only the products of X. The same goes for the reverse way.

Here is my progress so far [sandbox link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) and indented code are below

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myObject: {
        Tshirts: ["X", "Y", "Z"],
        Pants: ["A", "B", "C"],
        Coats: ["D", "E"],
      },
      selectedCategoryProducts: "",
      selectedCategorysSub: "",
    }
  },

  computed: {
    subForSelectedProducts() {
      // if selectedCategoryLocation is equal to the first
      var vm = this;
      var products = vm.selectedCategoryProducts;

      if (products === "All") {
        return vm.selectedCategorySub;
      } else {
        return vm.selectedCategorySub.filter(function (selectedCategorySub) {
          return myObject.key === products;
        });
      }
    },

    productsForSelectedSub() {
      var vm = this;
      var sub = vm.selectedCategorySub;
      if (sub === "All") {
        return vm.selectedCategoryProducts;
      } else {
        return vm.selectedCategoryProducts.filter(function (selectedCategoryProducts) {
          return myObject.name === sub;
        });
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <select v-model="selectedCategoryProducts">
    <option v-for="(value, key) in myObject" :key=key.id :value="value">
      {{ key }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div v-for="country in myObject">

    <select v-model="selectedCategorySub">
      <option v-for="country in country"> {{ country }} </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is that I can't display only one select option at the second part and overall, it is not working properly.

Comment: I think your example is incomplete. I don't see where you are using your computed properties in the template. Also for your first dropdown I would use the key of myObject as the v-model binding instead of the value (array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the model from `selectedCategoryProducts` to make populate the list of options. Because it will be empty initially, you can add a `v-if="selectedCategoryProducts"` to the select element to no show it unless the first option is selected. No need for using computed.

```html
<select v-model="selectedCategorySub" v-if="selectedCategoryProducts">
  <option  v-for="option in selectedCategoryProducts">{{ option }}</option>
</select>
```

[sfc example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it really helped a lot. Also, how can I keep the second option available as well at the beginning. So that the users can start searching from  second category too. Like the same thing but reverse.

Comment: one way is to create a computed that returns the concatenated list of all options available if the `selectedCategoryProducts` is not selected, otherwise return just the values based on `selectedCategoryProducts`. then use the output of that computed in the `v-for` of the option